# Checking for $ in a Greasemonkey script throws a '$ is not defined' and the script halts: why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm writing a script for a page that already uses jQuery, so I'm expecting the library to be already there and loaded.
But when I check for `$` definition, while I expect it to be false, I get a '$ is not defined' error (on the browser console - Firefox `Ctrl-Shift-J`) and the script halts:

```
if ($) {
    GM_log('jQuery through \'$\': ' + $.fn.jquery);
}
GM_log('end');
```

Why do I get such behaviour? Why doesn't that `if` statement just evaluate to `false` as it would when in a plain `<script>` element?

*Greasemonkey version: 1.15*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't like you trying to access things that don't exist. You should tell it where to try and look:

```
if( window.$) {
    // do something
}
```

In this case, it will look for the `window` object, then for the `$` property on that object, and return `undefined`, safe in the knowledge that at least it looked in the right place.

Note however that `window.$` is not a reliable way to detect jQuery - if you were to run that on my site, you'd get "cannot access property 'jquery' of undefined" because `$` is defined to be a "queue for execution just before `</body>`" function.

Comment: Better would be to check for `window.jQuery`.

Comment: @Barmar Yup. Even then, though, if I felt like screwing with botters on my game, I could set `window.jQuery = function() {while(1) alert('lol nice try');};`

Comment: I thought that with no object to refer to, the global object (i.e. `window` is a web browser) would be used (much like when declaring a variable without `var`).

Comment: @Barmar Why? Aren't they synonyms?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol About your suggestion, I guess there's no reliable way to test for real jQuery existence ;-) I just trust the fact that the specific website I'm working with isn't doing anything like that.

Comment: @watery `$` is used by a number of Javascript libraries as a synonym for the library name.